# File transfer error between Samsung Galaxy S3 and Ubuntu 12.04 over Bluetooth

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, bluetooth, linux

I got my Samsumg Galaxy S3 paired and connected over Bluetooth to my laptop running Ubuntu 12.04
Both the mobile and the laptop states that the bluetooth connection is up and running

I can query the mobile from the laptop with hcitool, for instance:

```
$ sudo hcitool con
Connections:
    > ACL [the_phone_mac_addr] handle 11 state 1 lm MASTER AUTH ENCRYPT
```

I can transfer files from the laptop to the phone using the ubuntu bluetooth menu, but if I try to transfer a file from the mobile to the laptop I alway got a "connection failed" error

My idea is that the problem might be with the bluetooth profiles the laptop exposes; from the mobile I can see the paired device details, and the list of profiles are:

- Call Audio
- Media Audio

Is there a way to add or enable profiles to the laptop?

Can anyone confirm my hypothesis?

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hypothesis is correct. It's like transferring files over FTP: the receiving computer needs to run a server that understands the right protocol. To receive files you probably want a server that understands the object exchange protocol (OBEX) or object push protocol (OPP).

Our sister site [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153652/no-receive-option-in-bluetooth-settings) has an answer about receiving files, which may help you out. If you need any further help setting up your Ubuntu laptop, they'll be able to help if you ask a question there.

Comment: The proposed link gave me the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

looks like u had the problem too  (i had it when i used ubuntu for my first time).

Please change your personal file sharing settings to get rid of this problem.

press the windows key on your keyboard and type "personal file sharing " in the search box appeared(on ubuntu 12.04)

then click on the folder with the exact name appeared in the search results ....

u may be taken to a window with some settings .................
 tic mark the box corresponding "share public files via bluetooth"

(that worked for me with my galaxy star with android jellybean os)

although no guaranteeee

just give it a shot!